# Action ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED not working after updating targetSdkVersion to 27

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

I am checking battery charging status, it was working fine before changing   targetSdkVersion to 26 and 27

```
<receiver
            android:name=".PowerConnectionReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

It is not working in latest targetSdkVersion 27
what will be the reason? and its solution?

Note: It working with Charger Type A but not working with Charger Type C

Comment: why downvote, Please explain your view before downvote

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions

Comment: do you know any solution over this?

Comment: see https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts#changes-system-broadcasts

Comment: thanks, the link was usefull